# rpm query on filesystem image

Tags: linux, rpm

I have a rootfs snapshot of an embedded ARM system that uses rpm as package manager, both as a binary image that can be loopback-mounted on my host and a tarball.

I'd like to issue some rpm queries on that snaphot, such as `rpm -qa` or `rpm -qf /some/file` and so on.

Is there a way to do that on my x86 host?

For now I have to resort to actually running the image under qemu-arm and doing the queries on a simulated target, but that's not a convenient way to do things.

I tried playing with `--dbpath` and `--root` options of `rpm` and `rpmdb`, to no avail (they just silently terminate without giving any errors).

Answer (score 0):

On my debian system, the qemu-user-static package contains statically linked user emulation (by opposition to system emulation) binaries, including /usr/bin/qemu-arm-static

They are all registered with the binfmt facility (by this package with the binfmt-support helper package). So for example:

```
# cat /proc/sys/fs/binfmt_misc/qemu-arm
enabled
interpreter /usr/bin/qemu-arm-static
flags: OC
offset 0
magic 7f454c4601010100000000000000000002002800
mask ffffffffffffff00fffffffffffffffffeffffff
```

Now just mount the arm's root filesystem to /mnt and copy /usr/bin/qemu-arm-static (x86 binary) to /mnt/usr/bin/qemu-arm-static

From your x86 host, just chroot:

```
chroot /mnt
```

And you can now run most commands and think you're on an arm system (qemu site documents what doesn't work, including ptrace calls). Don't forget to mount other filesystems (/proc, /var ...) if needed.

I think LXC can work with this kind of emulation inside a container. Doing a chroot won't isolate and installing packages can give problems (arm binary daemons running...)

You didn't tell what is your host's distribution so I can't tell much more. The manual method to add an interpreter for a binary executable is described there:
https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/binfmt_misc.txt